# sendmail.php - send email to variable AND email address

Tags: php, sendmail

I have a PHP sendmail script that sends to an email address from user input:

```
$to = $_POST['email'];
```

How do I add an actual email address to go alongside that - for example:

```
$to = $_POST['email', 'foo@bar.com'];
```

Thanks

Comment: `$to = array($_POST['email'],'foo@bar.com');`

Comment: I'm hoping the above comment is what you were looking for. But I never would have guessed that was what you were asking if it is.

Comment: I think you should transcribe that into an answer @ThomasRollet with a bit of *"oomf!"* too ;-)

Comment: Seeing your comment below; post more/full code including how you're sending mail, and something may be failing you somewhere. Form method, no name attributes etc. etc. error reporting will tell you that http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php - that's IF you're paying attention to comments here.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this and using an array:

```
$to = array($_POST['email'],'foo@bar.com');
```

Comment: This hasn't worked for me, I'm afraid? When I add that in, it it's not sending at all now. Is there anything else I should be doing?

Comment: Can you show me your send code ?